# Circle passing through a vertex of a triangle. Prove the following expression.

Tags: geometry

Given triangle *ABC*, let *D, E* be any points on *BC*. A circle through A cuts the
lines *AB, AC, AD, AE* at the points *P, Q, R, S,* respectively. Prove that

(*AP* .  *AB* -  *AR* . *AD*)/(*AS* . *AE* - *AQ* . *AC*) = *BD*/*CE*

What I did :
*BD*/*CE* is the same as  [*ABD*]/[*ACE*], so I tried finding the relation between the sides and areas of the  aforementioned triangles.  I am required to use power of point in the solution.

Comment: Sorry, what is meant by "power of point"?

Comment: @StephenDonovan: See Wikipedia's ["Power of a point" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point).

Comment: Ok, I think I've found a method that works: I began by using the intersecting secants theorem (on the same wiki page) to rewrite the products on the left-hand side in terms the squares of sides, after which using the law of cosines seems gross but actually ends up cancelling almost everything out. (I think this does require assuming that none of the other points are interior to the circle)

Comment: Hey, is everything going alright?